# Get a value from a Swift function in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am trying to get a value from a Swift function of a class I made.
The Swift file is recognized and properly included in a Objective C project via the MyProdName-Swift.h header. I can instanciate it, but I am not able to get a String from a function.

Swift class:

```
@objc public class Test : NSObject {

    @objc func getTest () -> NSString{

        return "tested"
    }
}
```

Objective C class:

```
Test *test = [Test new];
NSString *testDummy = test.getTest();
```

In the last line I get "Called object type 'NSString *' is not a function or function pointer".
So obviously I am making some basic mistake, please point me to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to call the method in Objective C using Swift method call syntax. You should be doing this:

```
NSString *testDummy = [test getTest];
```

Comment: Actually it was java, but you're right. I guess I should focus better.